# Fourier Transform of Indicator Function $\chi_{[-0.5,0.5]}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to compute

$\displaystyle(\mathcal{F}f)(k)=\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_{[-0.5,0.5]} e^{-ikx}\,\mathrm{d}x$

I proceeded as follows:

$\displaystyle(\mathcal{F}f)(k) =\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Then I argumented that, since $\sin$ is odd, the integral must be zero, so I am left with

$...= \int_{-0.5}^{0.5}\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2}{k}\sin(k/2)$

Is this correct?

Comment: The last integral is in $dx$, so $x$ cannot be in the result - it should only depend on $k$.

Comment: @lisyarus Corrected it.

Comment: Looks good for me now.